# Regex returns negative integers as positive

Tags: python, regex, integer, negative-number

I am scraping a web and extracting some values, from which I need only the numeric half. For example, if the string says "-14.32 kcal/mole", I want to get the float -14.32

To do this I am applying the following code:

```
import re

number_string = '-9.2 kcal/mole'


number = re.search(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", number_string).group()

print(number)
```

Output: -9.2

Whenever the number_string is a float it works fine. But when the number is a negative integer, I get the postive value of that number.

For example,

```
import re

number_string = '-4 kcal/mole'


number = re.search(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", number_string).group()

print(number)
```

Output: 4 (instead of -4)

Comment: Make the decimal-part optional through an non-capturing group, for example `[-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?`. I think you could even skip the alternation alltogether.

Comment: Your regular expression is *either* a sign and then a number with a decimal point, *or* a number without a sign and without a decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

`|` is the lowest priority operator. You are looking for a non-zero float

```
[-+]?\d*\.\d+
```

or an unsigned integer

```
\d+
```

You need to parenthesize the expression for matching the absolute value to make the sign apply to either:

```
[-+]?(?:\d*\.\d+|\d+)
```

or make the fractional part optional.

```
[-+]?\d*(?:.\d+)?
```

In both cases, I've used non-capture groups to avoid changing the semantics of the following call to the `groups` method.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this:

```regex
[+-]?(?:\d*\.)?\d+
```

- `[+-]?` - optional positive or negative sign
- `(?:\d*\.)?` - optional leading digits followed by decimal
- `\d+` - required digits

https://regex101.com/r/WKPQ4h/1

---

Since you are scraping web content this regex will simply find all numbers.

You will probably wish to target specific units of measurement:

```regex
[+-]?(?:\d*\.)?\d+(?= (?:kcal/mole|butterflies))
```

https://regex101.com/r/FM5ZXJ/1

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is set up to search for `[-+]?\d*\.\d+` or `\d+`, that is why it is happening. You can change you regular expression to something like `[-+]?\d*\.\d+|[-+]?\d+` and that should get your expected result.